# Converting non structured key value pairs data to a table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have data in the following format, sample shown below:

```
ValA=101
ValB=2938
ValA=998
ValB=387
ValA=876
ValB=9832
```

I know that each set of ValA & ValB are a set of values that belong together, so output will be:

```
ValA        ValB
101         2938
998         387
.......
.......
```

I need to get this into a tabular format so each valA ValB pair is one row.
Ive tried doing this in powerquery by splitting on the = sign and then pivoting on the Val name, but it doesnt work.

any idea on how this might be easily achieved in powerquery?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing the exact same as Lukasz, here's the full code:

```
let
    Source = "ValA=101
ValB=2938
ValA=998
ValB=387
ValA=876
ValB=9832",
    Custom1 = Lines.FromText(Source),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Custom1, Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("="), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    ChangedType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}}),
    CustomA = Table.AddColumn(ChangedType, "ValA", each if [Column1] = "ValA" then [Column2] else null),
    CustomB = Table.AddColumn(CustomA, "ValB", each if [Column1] = "ValB" then [Column2] else null),
    FilledDown = Table.FillDown(CustomB,{"ValA"}),
    FilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(FilledDown, each [ValB] <> null)
in
    FilteredRows
```

---

Lukasz's second idea using pivot columns looks like this:

```
let
    Source = "ValA=101
ValB=2938
ValA=998
ValB=387
ValA=876
ValB=9832",
    Custom1 = Lines.FromText(Source),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Custom1, Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("="), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    ChangedType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}}),
    AddedIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(ChangedType, "Index", 0, 1),
    IntegerDividedColumn = Table.TransformColumns(AddedIndex, {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 2), Int64.Type}}),
    PivotedColumn = Table.Pivot(IntegerDividedColumn, List.Distinct(IntegerDividedColumn[Column1]), "Column1", "Column2")
in
    PivotedColumn
```

The trick I found was to add divided-by-two index column (that goes 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2...) so the pivot knows the first two rows should be related, and the next two, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1) create two new calculated columns with logic like if column1 contains ValA then Column1 else null. same logic for ValB in second column.

2) use the fill down feature on the left most column.  This will produce rows with values for both ValA and ValB in distinct columns

3) use the filter feature to filter out rows that have nulls in your two new columns

That should give you what you want.

Edit: thinking about this more you might also try: split column1 on the equal sign.  Then pivot the new column and it should produce two columns with the discrete values.  HTH.